# UITableViewCell imageView cornerRadius and scale not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath function, I have a subtitle cell, and I change the cell imageView to be circular, but the change does not take effect when the view controller loads, and instead only changes after I refresh the tableview.

1) How do I load the circular imageView when the view controller first loads?

2) How do I scale the circular imageView to a smaller size? (i.e. 75% smaller)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

let url = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/\(self.userId)/picture")
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil

cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: error)!)
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.size.width / 2
cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true/false

Comment: You can add in `viewDidAppear:` the method `tableView.reloadData()`. It is caused because the size of the `imageView` is 0 when the view is loading. Another solution is to set the value of the cornerRadius directly and not depending on the `imageView` size.

Comment: Unfortunately the clipsToBounds idea did now work but the viewDidAppear solution worked well, thanks! Any idea on the second question I had regarding scaling?

Comment: @aramusss, Do you know how I can reduce the scale of the images in the cells (i.e. 75%)?

Comment: imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.75, 0.75);

Comment: Thanks, that works, but the imageView then loses its circular shape. What can I do about that?